# Skip OpenID approval screen when calling chrome.identity.getAuthToken

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-openid, chrome-web-store

According to [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/identify_user?hl=en-US#realm) of the Chrome Web Store,

> Your users will have a better experience if they never see the approval
>   screen

The above linked page states that for this to work it must satisfy both of these conditions:

1. Your app requests only the OpenID URL
2. You specify your app's OpenID realm in the Edit page

In regards to condition 1, I'm unsure what URLs are requested when calling `chrome.identity.getAuthToken`, but analyzing chrome://net-internals it seems that the following URLs are called:

- https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/IssueToken
- https://accounts.google.com/OAuthLogin?source=ChromiumBrowser&issueuberauth=1
- https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

As for condition 2, does anybody know what the OpenID Realm should be set to in the edit page of the Chrome Web Store?

[image: OpenID Realm]

Unfortunately most of the links in the documentation page appear to point to deprecated OAuth versions so I'm starting to think that this is no longer possible to achieve.

Comment: Bascially, `chrome.identity` has nothing to do with OpenID (which is deprecated). Don't expect Webstore docs to be up to date in that regard.